# Python check if listelement is in value but return the listelement it found instead of true

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
mylist = ['dog','cat','bird']

var = "*ç%&dog*ç%"

a = any(mylist for mylist in var)
print(a)
```

This returns true, but i wan't it to return "dog" as a string.
How can i do that?

Comment: a = [i for i in mylist if i in var] this will print 'dog' if it's found it.

Answer (score 1):

`any()` returns `True` if at least one of the elements in your list is `True`.

In your case, you better use list comprehension with condition:

```
a  = [x for x in mylist if x in var]
print(a)
```

Or you can use `filter`:

```
a = list(filter(lambda x: x in var, mylist))
print(a)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Now i need a check if the value does not contain a listelement.

Comment: If it helped you, show your gratitude by upvoting/accepting the answer.

Comment: I am too stupid to highlight code in replies, omg.

Comment: ```
mylist = ['dog','cat','bird']

var = "*ç%&dg*ç%"

if any(mylist for mylist in var) and var != None:
    retailer = [x for x in mylist if x in var]
    print(retailer)
else:
    print("honk") 
```

Comment: The expression `any(mylist for mylist in var)` is always `True`. It iterates over the characters of `var` and since each of the characters represents logical `True`, this expression equals `True` as well.

Comment: i need a check for the words in the list, not single characters and if the whole word isent present, it should give me a false.

Comment: `any(word in var for word in mylist)` will return `False` if no element in the list is a substring of `var`. Is it what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a function to handle checking the word contained in the string, and return that word back if it exists.

```
def fn(word, var):
    if word in var:
        return word
    else:
        return None


for element in mylist:
    print(fn(element, var))
```

Answer (score 0):

ok now it works:

```
retailer_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird']

webpage = ["*ç%&g*ç%", "*ç%vszcat", None, "bird"]

for retailer_find in webpage:
    if not retailer_find:
        continue

    retailer = [ele for ele in retailer_list if(ele in retailer_find)]

    if bool(retailer) == True:
        print(bool(retailer))
        print(retailer[0])
    else:
        print("Not in List")
```